# PHP background job stops when calling php script ends

Tags: php, linux, scp

On a LAMP box, I am calling the SCP copy function via PHP's exec function in a loop to copy several images to a remote server:

```
exec("scp ".$this->GetUploadPath(true)." ".$currentServer->Scp.":".$this->GetServerPath($currentServer, true));
```

Result: Works fine, but the PHP script takes several seconds to finish.

However I do not want the PHP script to wait for the SCP job to finish so I tried one the following:

```
exec("nohup scp ".$this->GetUploadPath(true)." ".$currentServer->Scp.":".$this->GetServerPath($currentServer, true) . " 1>/dev/null/ 2>&1 &");
```

Result: PHP script is much faster, however SCP is not finished. Images are not copied to the remote sever.

```
exec("nohup scp ".$this->GetUploadPath(true)." ".$currentServer->Scp.":".$this->GetServerPath($currentServer, true) . " &");
```

Result: Images are copied, however no improvement in php script running time, so I guess the php script still waits for the SCP routine to finish although I "backgrounded" the call.

Any ideas how to implement it, that the PHP script does not wait, but the SCP process is finished?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have u tried piping the output of the SCP command to a log file, that might have some info in on why the SCP is failing?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing in there. One error I found was that I deleted the local files too quick. However I commented the delete function out, but now 4 out of 10 images are copied. Error and output logs stay empty.

Comment: This is an educated guess but try ignore_user_abort(true); it may be that it's seeing the client disconnect and ending the script and it's child processes.

Comment: Now it is uploading some files and some not. The error message I got was: 
"ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection"

Comment: It seems to work better if I leave nohup away.

Comment: @user1876422 if you're connecting too fast at once, the remote host will deny connections. That's what causing the connection close. I'd use rsync and feed it a list of files to copy (--files-from option). If you don't want to use rsync and all files are in the same directory, just feed scp all filenames you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Exceeding the maximum simultaneous connection to the server could be the problem. So limit the simultaneous connections or simply upload it one by one. If waiting before the browser is your problem, you could add the following to your php script

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

and upload using looping the following

```
exec("scp ".$this->GetUploadPath(true)." ".$currentServer->Scp.":".$this->GetServerPath($currentServer, true) . " 1>/dev/null/ 2>&1");
```

after triggering the php script from your browser, you could even close browser, the above piece of code will do the magic for you.